# Firebase If child is equal to something remove that entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

[image]

What i am trying to do is for example im pulling pixidata from db,doing some calculations with it.if calculation result is for example > then 10,i want to remove that pixilats,pixilongs key.

How to write this kind of code ? im using angularfire. like with knowledge of child,i need to remove key.

This is how i get the data:

```
this.pixiData = this.db.list(`/pixidata/`).valueChanges();
this.pixiData.take(1).subscribe(pixi => {
  let pixidata = pixi.map(this.getObjectWithoutKnowingKey)
this.pixiData=pixidata;
```

getobject function:

```
     getObjectWithoutKnowingKey(data) {
    let objects = [];
    for (var propName in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        objects.push(data[propName]);
      }
    }
    return objects;
  }
```

thanks

Comment: Could `Cloud Functions` and `Realtime Database Triggers` be any help? Trigger a function when the value changes and remove the node if necessary. Check out the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: value is not changing.im pulling pixidata from db,doing some calculations with it.if calculation result is for example > then 10,i want to remove that pixilats,pixilongs key.

Comment: Oh, so you are simply asking [how to remove data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data)?

Comment: how to remove it without knowing the key ?.because im pulling all pixidata with valuechanges then subscribe.then for example pixidata[0] returns content of first key.pixidata[0][0] means dropper of first key for example

Comment: Please include an example of how you query and work with that data, that will make things easier…

Comment: i added it to first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to simply quote relevant parts of the `angularfire2` documentation around [Retrieving data as lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#valuechanges)

> ## valueChanges()
>
> […]
>
> **Why would you use it?** - When you just need a list of data. No snapshot
>   metadata is attached to the resulting array which makes it simple to
>   render to a view.
>
> **When would you not use it?** - When you need […] the key of each snapshot for data
>   manipulation methods. This method assumes you either are saving the
>   key for the snapshot data or using a "readonly" approach.
>
> ## snapshotChanges()
>
> […]
>
> **Why would you use it?** - When you need a list of data but also want to
>   keep around metadata. Metadata provides you the underyling
>   DatabaseReference and snapshot key. Having the snapshot's key around
>   makes it easier to use data manipulation methods. […]

Please try to either save the keys manually or retrieve them with your data using `snapshotChanges()` instead of `valueChanges()`.

Comment: i tried using snapshotChanges() but still couldnt get the key of message.

Comment: @rektandpepper you could update your question and include the new code. I'll have a look at it tomorrow :)

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Kc0pV6eBQaqSqQXPFpLKlg.png    i was triying this one it returns pixidata.i guess i need to go 1 more layer down :D

Comment: Where did you find that example? You should really update your question with your new code. There are multiple examples on the documentation page I mentioned that should work just fine!

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md from this page

Comment: @rektandpepper have you managed to solve your problem? Please update your code if not.